# Google Geocode, get state capital city or list of state cities

Tags: google-api, google-geocoder

Is it posible to get the state capital city, or the list of all cities of that state using google geocode?

when you make a query like this:

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Salto,%20Uruguay&sensor=true

The result is separated in types like locality, administrative_area_level_1, country, etc.

So, is there a way to get the "administrative_area_level_1" and fetch all is "localities"?

Answer (score -1):

Simple answer is no.

You can search for a destination, but you cannot get all the localities with a simple query.